# C# Cmdlet call GetChildItem

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm writting a c# cmdlet, and I need to use Get-ChildItems PowerShell cmdlet.
Nee

How can I call this cmdlet from my code, without invoking "string PowerShell command"? Basically I try to call the c# GetChildItem code.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "SampleCmdlet")]
public class GetSampleCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter()]
    public string Parameter1 { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        //Call c# Get-ChildItem and do something with results

        //Don't want to do somthing like:
        //string stringCommand = "Get-ChildItem 'c:\\*.Txt'";
        //InvokePowerShellCommand(stringCommand);

    }

}
```

I only need the FileSystemProvider, but it should be a way to call directly GetChildItem cmdlet.

Comment: I'm not if it's actually possible.. But why don't you use the static  EnumerateDirectories() and EnumerateFiles() methods which reside in System.IO.Directory? If you need file information you can then create a System.IO.FileInfo object (and for directories you can do the same). Basicly this is also how the Get-ChildItem cmdlet works.

Comment: Perhaps extend `PSCmdlet` instead and then call `InvokeProvider.ChildItem.Get(string path, bool recurse)`?

Comment: @bluuf, really not same funcitons. Don't want to implement "c:\*\folder*\*.txt" support, include, exclude, etc. 
@MathiasR.Jessen well done! I tested `new FileSystemProvider().InvokeProvider.ChildItem.Get("d:\\*.txt", false);` and didn't work with Cmdlet, but your tips did the trick. Limitation is I can't use this class in regular c# app, just writting it for next readers. Can you make a small answer, so I can validate it.

Comment: Sorry @MathiasR.Jessen I was probably confusing. 
Your tip is working, I was just saying what I tested BEFORE you answer. So do a PSCmdlet and call  `InvokeProvider.ChildItem.Get(string path, bool recurse)` is the answer I want to validate. Please just make a regular answer (not a comment), so I can validate it.

Comment: @Manea Yeah, understood as much when I re-read it ^_^ posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend `PSCmdlet` instead of `Cmdlet`, you can access the current provider through the `InvokeProvider` property - [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscmdlet?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=powershellsdk-1.1.0):

> If your Cmdlet requires access to the MSH Runtime (for example,
>   variables in the session state,  access to the host, or information
>   about **the current Cmdlet Providers**,) then you should instead  derive
>   from the PSCmdlet base class.

You can invoke the `Get-ChildItem` provider cmdlet via:

```
InvokeProvider.ChildItem.Get(@"C:\path\to\dir", false);
```